# Error mounting Windows partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I know this question has been asked before but the solution is always ntfsfix which ended up not working for me. The error message is:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/user/OS: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/samrat/OS"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I was trying to move something I downloaded on the Ubuntu partition to the windows partition so I need write privileges to do this. It's worked before but I suddenly got this error message. I booted into Windows 10 and made sure to shut down and boot into Ubuntu. Didn't work. ntfsfix didn't work and gave the following error message:

```
Mounting volume... Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
FAILED
Attempting to correct errors... 
Processing $MFT and $MFTMirr...
Reading $MFT... OK
Reading $MFTMirr... OK
Comparing $MFTMirr to $MFT... OK
Processing of $MFT and $MFTMirr completed successfully.
Setting required flags on partition... OK
Going to empty the journal ($LogFile)... OK
Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Remount failed: Operation not permitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probable cause: I think you have shutdown your PC before starting linux.

Solution:

1. start windows.
2. check disks for errors for those drives which are not mounted in linux.
3. start linux with a reboot (not with shutdown)

long term solution:

1. start windows.
2. check disks for errors for those drives which are not mounted in linux.
3. un-tick the fast-boot option in power settings of windows.

you are all set.

Answer (score 0):

Better turn off hibernation option from Windows as your windows doesn't go to shut down mode but it sleeps instead so harddisk is still holded by Windows

You can do

```
 sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdaX
```

Where x is the number shown in error

But this is highly dangerous , sometimes it might happen you save your data in Ubuntu on those drive and it wont be visible in Windows and then it vanishes from Ubuntu as well so turning off hibernation is recommended .